# Remove - ManyToOne - entity still exists

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm new in Hibernate, and I've started to do a little project.
I wanted to test add and remove for all kind of relashionship.
I do not understant how remove is managed ... (for ManyToMany it seems to works well)
(I use an H2 database)

I have a ManyToOne relashionship : 
WORK have 0 or many STEPS so : (java and sql at the end)

I have created some entities, and then I just want de remove a Work from database ...

**Details**

I have create a Junit to Test, and I display my database :

```
- save new work : "workOne"
- save new work : "workTwo"
- save new file : "fileone"
- save new step : "stepOne" 
  - stepOne.setWork(workOne)
- save new step : "stepTwo" 
  - stepOne.setWork(workOne)
  - stepOne.setFile(fileOne)
```

To save :

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.save(object);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Display (by sql request on database) >>> OK all my entity are displayed with the good associations :

```
workOne - ID = 10
workTwo - ID = 11

fileOne - ID = 20

stepOne - ID = 40 / ID_WORK = 10 / ID_DOS = null
stepTwo - ID = 41 / ID_WORK = 11 / ID_DOS = 20
```

Now I want to test remove a work (in the same test)

```
// Remove a work
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.remove(workOne);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
// Display BDD
>> The workOne has not been deleted from database ... (no hibernate delete on logs)
```

I Expected that :

1. workOne (#10) would be deleted
2. stepOne too ... (because we cannot have a step with no work)

Thanks,

**java :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_WORK")
public class Work {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private long id = 0L;
  @Column(name = "LABEL")
  String label;

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_STEP")
public class Step{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private long id = 0L;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL })
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_WORK")
  Work work;

  @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL })
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_FILE")
  File file;

  @Column(name = "LABEL")
  private String label;
  @Column(name = "STATUS")
  private String status;
```

**h2.sql :**

```
create table T_WORK (
ID number(10) not null,
LABEL varchar2(64) not null,
constraint PK_WORK primary key (ID)
);

create table T_STEP (
ID number(10) not null,
ID_WORK number(10) not null,
ID_FILE number(10),
LABEL varchar2(64) not null,
STATUS varchar2(64),
constraint PK_STEP primary key (ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_STEPS_WORK FOREIGN KEY (ID_TRA) REFERENCES T_WORK(ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_STEP_FILE FOREIGN KEY (ID_DOS) REFERENCES T_FILE(ID)
);
```

Comment: Where is your @OneToMany relationship between work and step?

Comment: It is an unidirectionnal relationship. I just need to add relation by editing Steps.